# How to convert milliseconds to date and time format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

I have a value in milliseconds in a Python program. For example: `1557975599999`

And I would like to convert it to a string with days and hours, minutes, seconds. How can I do this?

Comment: Is it correct to assume that this value is a "unix timestamp"  - time since the epoch? Is it actually in microseconds, not in milliseconds?

Answer (score 8):

To convert [unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) to datetime, you can use [`datetime.fromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp). The only problem, that your timestamp is in miliseconds, but function expect timestamp in seconds. To cut miliseconds you can divide timestamp to 1000.

**Code:**

```
from datetime import datetime

a = 1557975599999
date = datetime.fromtimestamp(a // 1000)
print(date)
```

**Output:**

```
2019-05-16 05:59:59
```

---

**Upd.**

[@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3555845/daniel) in comments noticed that `fromtimestamp()` accept floats, so we can save miliseconds from original timestamp. All we need is just to remove one symbol :D

```
date = datetime.fromtimestamp(a / 1000)
```

Answer (score 4):

With Pandas’ `to_datetime()`

```
import pandas as pd

pd.to_datetime(a, unit='ms')

# Or with a dataframe(column):
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Millisecond_time'], unit='ms')
```